# Extract URL from string javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, url

Here is my variable from which I want to extract only URL, for example in this case I want at the end the result: http://url.com/index.php/foo/bar/new/key/34941cd947592adb1594b6f649468a33/

```
var variable = "function onclick(event) { setLocation('http://url.com/index.php/foo/bar/new/key/34941cd947592adb1594b6f649468a33/')}"
```

Comment: Why are you storing JavaScript as a string in a JavaScript variable? Functions are objects too, you can just assign them to variables `var foo = function(){}`

Comment: @elclanrs If he did it as a function instead of string, how would he extract the URL from it?

Comment: @Barmar I think what he meant to ask is how that variable ended up with a piece of code inside.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this:

```
var testUrl = variable.match(/'(http:[^\s]+)'/),
    onlyUrl = testUrl && testUrl[1];
```

The `onlyUrl` variable contains the extracted URL or `null`.

**EDIT:**

*Previous was just answer to OP. Following an update to take care of https:*

```
var testUrl = variable.match(/'(https?:[^\s]+)'/),
    onlyUrl = testUrl && testUrl[1];
```

Comment: Nice Daniel, Thank you very much!

Comment: +1. I've improved the answer by not relying on `RegExp.$1` and making sure there are no errors when the URL can't be matched.

Comment: might be better off using `.exec` in that case

Comment: @DGS I don't see how that would make things simpler.

Comment: Actually, this answer isn't fully correct.  The resulting `onlyUrl` variable also contains all the text *after* the URL.  Also, this would fail if the scheme for the URL was something other than `http` (e.g. `https`).